# Python decimal showing up as Decimal("num") instead of num itself

Tags: python, json, decimal

```
from decimal import Decimal


num = Decimal(171.33334060048446)

json = {
    "num": num
}

print(json)
```

Output:
`{'num': Decimal('171.33334060048446190194226801395416259765625')}`

Instead, I am trying to put num as a number like this
`{'num': 171.33334060048446190194226801395416259765625}`

How can I do that?

I have tried converting num to a string but I am unable to remove the quotation marks before and after inside the json object.

Comment: I want to make sure you understand the key point in the correct answer below.  You cannot represent `171.33334060048446190194226801395416259765625` in JSON as a number.  It is not possible.  Floating point numbers in JSON are IEEE-754 double-precision values, which are limited to 15 or 16 decimal digits.  If you need 44 digits, which is EXTREMELY unlikely, then you enter it as a string.

Comment: @TimRoberts "*You cannot represent 171.33334060048446190194226801395416259765625 in JSON as a number.*": JSON is just a format; it can't prevent one from writing a number with an arbitrary number decimal places, as long as they have enough memory. It should be clarified that stringifying/parsing and storing such precise numbers are the actual impossible things.

Comment: There is no "json object" in your code, nothing here has anything to do with JSON

Answer (score 3):

There is no native way to represent a `Decimal` object in JSON (which only supports strings, booleans, integers, floats, maps/dictionaries/objects, and arrays).

You have a couple of options:

1. Convert the `Decimal` into a `float` value (which discards the precision):

   ```
   data = {
       "num": float(num)
   }
   ```

   Which gets you:

   ```
   >>> data = {"num": float(num)}
   >>> print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
   {
     "num": 171.33334060048446
   }
   ```
2. Serialize the `Decimal` to a string, and manually convert it back into a `Decimal` when you de-serialize the JSON:

   ```
   data = {
     "num": str(num)
   }
   ```

   Which gets you:

   ```
   >>> data = {"num": str(num)}
   >>> print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
   {
     "num": "171.33334060048446190194226801395416259765625"
   }
   ```

---

The advantage to option 1 is that code over which you don't have control can read in the JSON file and get a numeric value.  The disadvantage -- as Buzz Moschetti points out in a comment -- is that the lost precision can be the Road to Awfulville.

The advantage to option 2 is that it preserve the accuracy of the Decimal type, but you need to run custom code when de-serializing the JSON in order to retrieve the `Decimal` value.

Comment: I voted up the answer because of its breadth but option 1 is on the road to Awfulville.   10.09 turns into 10.0899999999999.   The only way to move penny-precise numerics through JSON is as a string.
Of course, you could always look at BSON.   ;-)

Comment: *The only way to move penny-precise numerics through JSON is as a string* -- Or as integral pennies.  Multiply by 100.  That's a common technique.